# Error with pycnophy R function from predicts library

Tags: r, interpolation

I am attempting to use the `pycnophy()` function from the `rspatial/predicts` library. Upon prepping county level data with a "population" metric and running these data through the function, I get the following error:

`#> Error in if (max(abs(old.x - xx)) < stopper) break: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I have tried fiddling with the arguments, to no avail. See the reprex below:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tmap)
library(predicts)
#> Loading required package: terra
#> terra 1.6.17
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

countyurl = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_500k.zip"

tdir=tempdir()

if(file.exists(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_county_500k.shp",sep=""))==F){
  download.file(countyurl,destfile = file.path(tdir,"Counties.zip"))
  unzip(file.path(tdir,"Counties.zip"),exdir=tdir)}

NYC_County_names = c("Kings","Queens","Bronx","Richmond","New York")

NYS_Counties_exNYC=read_sf(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_county_500k.shp",sep="")) %>%
  filter(STATEFP=="36") %>%
  st_transform(.,crs=32618) %>%
  filter(!c(NAME%in%NYC_County_names))

DF = data.frame(County = c("Albany",
                               "Allegany",
                               "Broome",
                               "Cattaraugus",
                               "Cayuga",
                               "Chautauqua",
                               "Chemung",
                               "Chenango",
                               "Clinton",
                               "Columbia",
                               "Cortland",
                               "Delaware",
                               "Dutchess",
                               "Erie",
                               "Essex",
                               "Franklin",
                               "Fulton",
                               "Genesee",
                               "Greene",
                               "Hamilton",
                               "Herkimer",
                               "Jefferson",
                               "Lewis",
                               "Livingston",
                               "Madison",
                               "Monroe",
                               "Montgomery",
                               "Nassau",
                               "Niagara",
                               "Oneida",
                               "Onondaga",
                               "Ontario",
                               "Orange",
                               "Orleans",
                               "Oswego",
                               "Otsego",
                               "Putnam",
                               "Rensselaer",
                               "Rockland",
                               "St. Lawrence",
                               "Saratoga",
                               "Schenectady",
                               "Schoharie",
                               "Schuyler",
                               "Seneca",
                               "Steuben",
                               "Suffolk",
                               "Sullivan",
                               "Tioga",
                               "Tompkins",
                               "Ulster",
                               "Warren",
                               "Washington",
                               "Wayne",
                               "Westchester",
                               "Wyoming",
                               "Yates"),
                    inc_per_hund = c(33,
                                     0,
                                     3.6,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     1.2,
                                     2.1,
                                     2.5,
                                     224.6,
                                     0,
                                     6.6,
                                     36.3,
                                     0,
                                     34.1,
                                     4,
                                     9.3,
                                     0,
                                     82.1,
                                     0,
                                     3.2,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     12.2,
                                     0.4,
                                     0,
                                     0.4,
                                     0.2,
                                     0,
                                     13.4,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     3.3,
                                     29.3,
                                     105,
                                     2.1,
                                     5.5,
                                     55.5,
                                     10.4,
                                     35.1,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                                     2.1,
                                     6.7,
                                     2.1,
                                     4.8,
                                     42.4,
                                     12.4,
                                     163.4,
                                     1.1,
                                     3.4,
                                     0,
                                     0))  

spatial_df = left_join(NYS_Counties_exNYC,DF,by=c("NAME"="County")) 

v <- vect(spatial_df)
r <- rast(v, resolution = 1000)
p <- pycnophy(r, v, "inc_per_hund", converge=3, verbose=FALSE)
#> Error in if (max(abs(old.x - xx)) < stopper) break: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

UPDATE:

The method runs when excluding counties past a certain point:

```
v=vect(mapdf %>% filter(NAME%in%c("Albany",
                                  #"Allegany",
                                  "Broome",
                                 # "Cattaraugus",
                                  "Cayuga",
                                  #"Chautauqua",
                                  "Chemung",
                                  "Chenango",
                                  "Clinton",
                                  "Columbia",
                                  "Cortland",
                                  "Delaware",
                                  "Dutchess",
                                  #"Erie",
                                  "Essex",
                                  "Franklin",
                                  "Fulton",
                                  #"Genesee",
                                  "Greene",
                                  "Hamilton",
                                  "Herkimer",
                                  "Jefferson",
                                  "Lewis",
                                  #"Livingston",
                                  "Madison",
                                  #"Monroe",
                                  "Montgomery",
                                  "Nassau",
                                  #"Niagara",
                                  "Oneida",
                                  "Onondaga",
                                  #"Ontario",
                                  "Orange",
                                  #"Orleans",
                                  "Oswego",
                                  "Otsego",
                                  "Putnam",
                                  "Rensselaer",
                                  "Rockland",
                                  "St. Lawrence",
                                  "Saratoga",
                                  "Schenectady",
                                  "Schoharie",
                                  "Schuyler",
                                  "Seneca",
                                  #"Steuben",
                                  "Suffolk",
                                  "Sullivan",
                                  "Tioga",
                                  "Tompkins",
                                  "Ulster",
                                  "Warren",
                                  "Washington",
                                  "Wayne",
                                  "Westchester",
                                  #"Wyoming",
                                  "Yates"))) 
r=rast(v,resolution=1000)
p <- pycnophy(r, v, pop="inc_per_hund", converge=3, verbose=FALSE)
```

Notably, many of these counties have "0" values for the "population". Unsure if location or value is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in "predicts" version 0.1-9

```
library(predicts)
tdir=tempdir()

f <- file.path(tdir, "cb_2018_us_county_500k.shp")
if (!file.exists(f)){
    url = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_500k.zip"
    zipf <- file.path(tdir, basename(url))
    download.file(url, destfile = zipf, mode="wb")
    unzip(zipf, exdir=tdir)
}

x <- vect(f)
NYC_County_names = c("Kings","Queens","Bronx","Richmond","New York")
x <- x[(x$STATEFP=="36") & !(x$NAME %in% NYC_County_names), ]
DF <- data.frame(
 County = c('Albany', 'Allegany', 'Broome', 'Cattaraugus', 'Cayuga', 'Chautauqua', 'Chemung', 'Chenango', 'Clinton', 'Columbia', 'Cortland', 'Delaware', 'Dutchess', 'Erie', 'Essex', 'Franklin', 'Fulton', 'Genesee', 'Greene', 'Hamilton', 'Herkimer', 'Jefferson', 'Lewis', 'Livingston', 'Madison', 'Monroe', 'Montgomery', 'Nassau', 'Niagara', 'Oneida', 'Onondaga', 'Ontario', 'Orange', 'Orleans', 'Oswego', 'Otsego', 'Putnam', 'Rensselaer', 'Rockland', 'St. Lawrence', 'Saratoga', 'Schenectady', 'Schoharie', 'Schuyler', 'Seneca', 'Steuben', 'Suffolk', 'Sullivan', 'Tioga', 'Tompkins', 'Ulster', 'Warren', 'Washington', 'Wayne', 'Westchester', 'Wyoming', 'Yates'),
 inc_per_hund = c(33, 0, 3.6, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 2.1, 2.5, 224.6, 0, 6.6, 36.3, 0, 34.1, 4, 9.3, 0, 82.1, 0, 3.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.2, 0.4, 0, 0.4, 0.2, 0, 13.4, 0, 0, 3.3, 29.3, 105, 2.1, 5.5, 55.5, 10.4, 35.1, 0, 0, 0, 2.1, 6.7, 2.1, 4.8, 42.4, 12.4, 163.4, 1.1, 3.4, 0, 0)
) 
x <- project(x, "EPSG:32618")

v <- merge(x, DF, by.x="NAME", by.y="County")
r <- rast(v, resolution = 1000)
p <- pycnophy(r, v, "inc_per_hund", converge=3, verbose=FALSE)
plot(p); lines(v)
```

[image]

As you suspected, the problem was caused by having polygons with values of zero. A simple work-around with the current released version is

```
v <- v[v$inc_per_hund > 0, ]
p <- pycnophy(r, v, "inc_per_hund", converge=3, verbose=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for making the fix. However, is there a reason zero values aren't included? Realistically, they are part of the data. Without them, counties are not influenced by neighboring counties with zeros. I can also run the code above by adding 0.00001 to all values to get a "desired" result.